# file writing: works well when compiling directly on terminal but not when through Qt 5

Tags: c++, qt, file-handling

Im writing the following code to write a value from a function to a file.

```
int main(){

     ofstream myfile;
     myfile.open("data1.txt");
     double angle = image();
     myfile<<angle<<"\r";  
     cout<<"abc";std::cout<<angle<<"\n";
     myfile.close();
     return 0;
}
```

when complied and run directly on terminal, the file is updated.
BUT, if i run tthe out file from inside qt creator using std::system command, file is not updated, the previous value is retained.

from qt creator i call:

```
std::system("./binaryName");
```

where "binaryName" is my out file
what might be happening?

Comment: There's no error checking, what if there's errors? But most likely the parent process current working directory is something else than you expect it to be.

Comment: Also, are you sure you want output a *carriage return* to the file and not a newline?

Comment: Have an absolute path (eg /tmp/test)

Comment: qt creator by default uses option "build in different place". It is usually: `..\<project-name>-<build-type>\` relative to your project directory.

Comment: Check return values as Joachim Pilebord suggests. Using a relative path, you're relying on the working directory, don't do that.